# a problem on differentiation set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $k∈[0,∞)$  be a real number. Define
$f_k(t)$=$t^k$sin($1/t$) ,if  $t≠0$    and    $0$ if $t=0$ .
Let $A$={$k∈[0,∞) : f_k$ is differentiable} . then $A$=?

i am not sure how to solve this problem.can anybody help me.

Comment: $\lim_{t\to 0}f_0(t)$  does not exist, but for $f_1(t)$ it exists.

Comment: There is no doubt that $t^k\sin(1/t)$ is *right-differentiable* at $t=0$ for all $k\gt 1$. And under the usual conventions, it is differentiable at $t=0$ for integers $x\gt 1$. One can extend this to $k=p/q\gt 1$, where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime positive integers, and $q$ is not divisible by $2$. But for general $k\gt 1$, like $k=\sqrt{2}$, there is the issue that $t^k$ is not defined for negative $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The function $f_k(t)=t^k\sin(1/t)$ will be differentiable for all $k\geq 0$ when $t>0$, so the only potential problem is $t=0$.  At that point, use the definition of the derivative. $$f_k^{'}(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{h^{k}\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)}{h}.$$ So for which $k$  does $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}h^{k-1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)$$ exist?

> **Note:** I am assuming that $f_k:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and that we do not define $f_k$ on the negative integers.  This is because, as André Nicolas points out, for negative $t$, there is not clear definition of that $t^k$ means for every $k$.